# Sharepoint Design

Tags: sharepoint-designer, design, design-manager, designer

I am developing the sharepoint (web) for my team in the company I work for. I am trying to change the background but there is no option to change it in this version (not like old one with the get started part). This version only shows the "get started" to add applications not to change the design. How can I change the background or at least add color to it?

Mine look like the first picture and Im trying to do the background like in the second picture:[image]
[image]

Comment: The first picture is how I want my sharepoint to look (with color). The second one is how it actually look.

Comment: This is quite possible, you would need to customize masterpage in a way that it will look like your first image. This article might help you getting started with: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/overview-of-design-manager-in-sharepoint